I just want to update state but don't want to emit flutter_bloc
In my case I just want to update state values and use that state value in bloc/cubit only but don't want to emit that value at that time but want to emit that value after some time.
I am using flutter_bloc plugin from pub.dev
If you have any Idea like that please let me know

Share your code that you have tried.

You can use  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); then emit the state.

You can Update the state value internally without emitting a new state by:
emit(state.copyWith(value: event.newValue));

Also, You can Schedule the emission of the updated state after a delay
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
emit(state);

If this is not the answer to your question give me more info about what you want.
